# Multi-module Spring Boot and start-class

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have made my application multi-module with the plan of eventually splitting them into multiple repos.

I'm having problems figuring out how to make `mvn spring-boot:run` work with my layout (which may be the problem).

actually directory structure is

```
 xenoterracide/
     rpf/
     rpf-application/
```

when I run `mvn test` from `xenoterracide` that passes fine, and when I start my `Application` class that works fine.

if I cd into `rpf-application` and run `mvn compile` it tells me that it can't find the dependencies, I'm guessing this is because things are meant to be run from the repository root.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building rpf-application 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.xenoterracide:security-rbac-jpa:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.xenoterracide:http:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.xenoterracide:rpf-domain:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.xenoterracide:rpf-liquibase:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

if I try to set the `start-class` in the `xenoterracide/pom.xml` it tells me it can't find the class (because of course it's in rpf-application).

`rpf-application/pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>rpf</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../rpf/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>rpf-application</artifactId>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.xenoterracide.RpfApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- internal -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
        <artifactId>security-rbac-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
        <artifactId>http</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
        <artifactId>rpf-domain</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
        <artifactId>rpf-liquibase</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

`rpf/pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>xenoterracide</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>rpf</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>../rpf-domain</module>
    <module>../rpf-application</module>
    <module>../rpf-liquibase</module>
</modules>
```

`pom.xml`

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
<artifactId>xenoterracide</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>util</module>
    <module>http</module>
    <module>security-rbac-api</module>
    <module>security-rbac-jpa</module>
    <module>hibernate</module>
    <module>entity-jpa</module>
    <module>rpf</module>
    <module>test-repositories</module>
    <module>entity-api</module>
</modules>
<properties>
    <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
```

how can I make `mvn spring-boot:run` work from either the root of the repository (xenoterracide) or from `rpf-application`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also have a multi-project Spring Boot app and you can't do it from the parent since there could be multiple modules and it would not know which to run.  You can do it from the child module if you first install the rest of the project to local Maven repository.  So from your xenoterracide run:

```
mvn install
```

Assuming that works it will put your SNAPSHOT versions into your local repository.  You can then change to your rpf-application and then run:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I've never really used this as a way to run it so maybe you can explain what your need is and we can see if there is another way that may be better.  I did do it with my project and it works but you have to be conscious of where the working directory is for your environment specific configuration files.

Comment: I have a friend who I was/am trying to sell on migrating to java/spring io as  a development stack, and I told him the easy way to run it (without an IDE, he's blind) and it didn't work, I didn't know other ways, because currently I either run the test suite, or I start the application class directly (my app hasn't gotten to a state where I wish it deployed yet). I have of course encouraged him to look at simpler apps. I think for him a very terminal oriented workflow would be the best. doing install then run wouldn't be  a problem, does that work with the new dev tools?

Comment: I don't think that would be a problem.  I use IntelliJ for my project.  You can set up your own scripts as well.  Hopefully this answer is what you were looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to have this setup without having to run mvn install every time a change is made to a sub module? Maybe a eclipse plugin?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Eclipse but it may be possible.  You can possibly use the Spring Boot Dev Tools to reload in your IDE when a change is made if that is what you are looking for.